# Windows installation USB not detected

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb

BIOS setup:

```
Boot List Option:  Legacy
Secure Boot:       Disabled
Boot Option #1:    USB Storage Device
```

Current installed OS: Debian

I followed https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive to download Windows10, have it formatted to **NTFS** (FAT32 doesn't support single file larger than 5GB) and then copied Windows10.iso into it. Now my desktop couldn't detect this USB: After pressing F12, there is no such an option as `booting from USB`. How do I fix it to install Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

A specialized application is needed to make a bootable USB from an ISO file.
Below are listed two such products.

Perhaps the best known such application is
[UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

**WinUSB**

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

To format a drive and install the ISO on it:

```
sudo winusb --format <iso path> <device>
```

To install a Windows ISO on an NTFS partition and edit the MBR of the device:

```
sudo winusb --install <iso path> <partition>
```

**UNetBootin**

This utility is more complex to operate.

See installation instructions on the
[UNetBootin website](http://unetbootin.github.io/).

One tutorial for creating a bootable USB can be found in the article
[Creating a Windows 10 Bootable USB for a UEFI BIOS within Linux](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/creating-a-windows-10-bootable-usb-for-a-uefi-bios-within-linux/).